# Find a matching string with substring easy selection

Tags: python, string

Is it possible to find a matching string in this boolean expression:

```
name1 in a_string or name2 in a_string
```

in a more concise way to create an expression that follows such a logic:

```
name{1,2} in a_string:
```

EDIT: nameX could be a variable and it could also be a string, "nameX" (but not both, so a separate solution would be ok).

Comment: `any([globals()[f'name{i}'] in string for i in [1, 2]])`

Comment: are both of the name1 and name2 are different variables?

Comment: Variables or strings. Thanks. Just added an edit.

Answer (score 0):

there's a way but it's looks even worse than what actual statement was the below approach is cool if you have 100+ variable and only differ in name by some thing :

```py
>>> a_string = "yoyo is a toy"
>>> name1 = "yoyo"
>>> name2 = "toy"
>>> mystr = "print({}{} in a_string)"
>>> exec(compile("\n".join([mystr.format("name", i) for i in range(1,3)]), filename="<string>", mode="exec"))
True
True
>>>
```

for detailed understanding read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile)

Disclaimer : above code is just for understanding purpose hope you will edit code so that it will do the same work as you want.

Comment: Indeed, I do have many variables :)

Comment: instead of `range(1,3)` you can just do it like `[1,2]` , {1,2}` , `(1,2)` or more like that in a simple way

Comment: checkout the link given in answer i made an edit to link formatting.

Comment: @GhostOps but that approach will gonna become an headache to add 100 numbers if you have hundred variables

Comment: @KunalSharma nvm, i just forget about that for a minute

Comment: @GhostOps that's ok **To err is human**.